# Rails App on Heroku - Redirect from .com to .org

Tags: ruby-on-rails, web-applications, mod-rewrite, heroku

For a Rails application hosted on Heroku, we are using Zerigo DNS Add-on to point a custom domain (say mydomain.org) to point to the Heroku app. We have SSL certificate registered for mydomain.org

Now, we would want mydomain.com to redirect to mydomain.org. We tried implementing redirect rules at the controller/rack level. Doesn't work. The browser URL still points to .com instead of .org

Has anybody faced the same problem with an Heroku app!!?

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you tried and how it failed other than "doesn't work?"

Comment: I used Rack::ForceDomain (http://theadmin.org/articles/2010/06/10/daily-code-reading-rack-force-domain/). Actually in firebug, it shows a 301 from .com to .org, but the browser URL remains still at .com

Comment: In the application controller, based on the hostname coming in the request, I used a regex based search for presence of ".com" to redirect to ".org". Same issue as mentioned in previous comment.

Comment: Can you post some of the code that "doesn't work" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used the following technique to redirect from "example.com" to "www.example.com" (as described here, http://docs.heroku.com/custom-domains).  This might work in your case to redirect from .com to .org.

In **app/controllers/application_controller.rb**:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery

  before_filter :ensure_domain

  protected

  def ensure_domain
    if request.env['HTTP_HOST'] != 'www.example.com' && Rails.env.production?
      redirect_to "http://www.example.com", :status => 301
    end  
  end

end
```

In your case, you would point the DNS records for your .com and .org domains to your app running on Heroku. Your app would check the HTTP_HOST to see if it specifies your .org URL.  If it does not, then it would redirect to your .org URL.

Comment: `ensure_domain` doesn't belong in a controller class (it will work, just as SQL in a controller class will work, but nevertheless doesn't belong there) - it belongs in a Rack middleware, which should be `config.middleware.use`'d from within `config/environments/production.rb`.

Comment: @Justice: This was pulled from the URL linked to on Heroku. You should write them if you feel you have a compelling argument here (and it would seem you do) since a lot more people will use that reference than this one.

Comment: This happens to be the easiest way to do it. It's just not quite as clean as the way I mentioned, because it introduces a dependency on the environment into the controller (that should be relegated to the config) and it introduces a dependency on the domain name into the controller (that should also be relegated to the config). If the Heroku sample works and the concerns I list are not an issue for you, there's no harm in going with it. If your code gets more complex, though, you may consider my suggestion.

Comment: @Justice: I use this method for a pretty small app. However, you make a good point about possibly wanting to separate this type of logic from a larger, more complex app. Also, in my case, I define the URL strings in a config file so that they are external to the application code, like you suggested. I would definitely recommend this.

Comment: I believe when you do this with Rack middleware the entire Rails stack is not loaded - certainly a lot of code is bypassed altogether - so there is also a performance benefit as well.